# when loading data from multiple tables into a single table in hive?

Tags: hive

I have a hive empty table of a particular structure.

I have 10 other tables of the same structure and datatype and schema but different table names.

I loaded data of one table into the empty table using "insert into" and say i have 10 mil records.

Now I am loading the second table into this table using "insert into".

When I do a count(*), it is not showing me the entire count of records.

It is displaying only the record count of the last loaded table.

Why is that? I want all the records to be loaded.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

do this,

```
insert into table table_name
Select *  from 
(
    SELECT b.var1 FROM tmp_table1 b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.var1 FROM tmp_table2 c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.var1 FROM tmp_table3 d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.var1 FROM tmp_table4 e
    UNION ALL
    SELECT f.var1 FROM tmp_table5 f
    UNION ALL
    SELECT g.var1 FROM tmp_table6 g
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h.var1 FROM tmp_table7 h
) CombinedTable
```

Comment: I cant load data from multiple tables into a single table using insert into?
Just curious, as per documentation, insert into will append the table right?
Can you explain what you are doing in this query?

Comment: follow the updated answer. select query  union all table and insert into final table.

Comment: Isnt there any other way? there are 53 columns in each table. It will take a lot of time if I do union of all the tables. Each table has around 20 - 50 mil recrods each.

Answer (score 0):

You are having same schema for all the table so it's better to copy the files to new empty table. this is better a solution if you don't have any partitions in hive table.

Comment: No, I wanted all the data in a single table. That is why I went for this approach of loading into a single table using insert into command.

Comment: just copy the files to a new table like
hadoop fs -cp /user/hive/db.old1  /user/hive/db.new/ 
this will work if you don't have Hcatalog